# How can I break this code up into two RequireJs modules

Tags: requirejs, amd

I've created the code below to dynamically load 2 buttons into an element with an ID of `masthead`. Then a function called `showMenus` runs when each button is clicked, running some jQuery animations. Everything is wrapped inside of a RequireJS module.

The code works fine as is but I'm thinking it may be better to break it up into two separate RequireJS modules/files: one that loads the buttons on the page and another one that runs the `showMenus` function. I did refer to the [RequireJS API docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) but couldn't find an answer.

Any help is appreciated...thanks in advance!

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {

  var header = document.getElementById("masthead"),
  $navMenu = $("#site-navigation-list"),
  $searchBox = $("#searchform"),
  menuButton = document.createElement("div"),
  searchButton = document.createElement("div"),
  showMenus;

  $(menuButton).attr("id", "menu");
  $(searchButton).attr("id", "search");

  header.appendChild(searchButton);
  header.appendChild(menuButton);

  // break the code below into its on RequireJS module?

  showMenus = function(btn,el) {
  $(btn).click(function() {
    if (el.is(":visible") ) {
      el.slideUp({
        complete:function(){
          $(this).css("display","");
        }
      });
     } else {
      el.slideDown();
     }
  });
};

showMenus(menuButton, $navMenu);
showMenus(searchButton, $searchBox);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows is only my opinion, but you might find it useful.

It might help to think in terms of things that your app is made of, and then maybe they are candidates for modules. So in your example, a 'masthead' seems to be a thing that you are interested in.

So using RequireJS, we can create a new module representing a generic masthead:

```
// Masthead module
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

    function showMenus (btn, el) {
        function toggle (el) {
            if (el.is(":visible")) {
                el.slideUp({
                    complete:function(){
                        $(this).css("display","");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                el.slideDown();
            }
        }
        $(btn).click(function() {
            toggle(el);
        });
    }

    // A Masthead is an object that encapsulates a masthead DOM element.
    // This is a constructor function.
    function Masthead (mastheadElement) {
        // 'this' is the masthead object that is created with the 'new'
        // keyword in your application code.
        // We save a reference to the jQuerified version of mastheadElement.
        // So mastheadElement can be a DOM object or a CSS selector.
        this.$mastheadElement = $(mastheadElement);
    }

    // Add a method to Masthead that creates a normal button
    Masthead.prototype.addButton = function (id) {
        var $btn = $("<div/>").attr("id", id);

        this.$mastheadElement.append($btn);

        return $btn;
    };

    // Add a method to Masthead that creates a 'toggling' button
    Masthead.prototype.addTogglingButton = function (id, elementToToggle) {
        // ensure we have a jQuerified version of element
        elementToToggle = $(elementToToggle);

        // Reuse the existing 'addButton' method of Masthead.
        var $btn = this.addButton(id);

        showMenus($btn, elementToToggle);

        return $btn;
    };

    // return the Masthead constructor function as the module's return value.
    return Masthead;
});
```

And then use this module in our actual application code:

```
// Application code using Masthead module
require(["Masthead"], function (Masthead) {
    // We create a new Masthead around an existing DOM element
    var masthead = new Masthead("#masthead");
    // We add our buttons.
    masthead.addTogglingButton("menu", "#site-navigation-list");
    masthead.addTogglingButton("search", "#searchform");
});
```

The advantage of this approach is that no DOM ids are hard-coded into the module. So we can reuse the Masthead module in other applications that require this functionality, but which may be using different DOM ids.

It might be convenient to think of this as separating the *what things are* from the *how we use them*.

This is a simple example, but frameworks/libraries like [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) and [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) (and many, many more) take this further.

Comment: Paul: I'm indebted to you and really appreciate the time that you took to create and comment on this code as well as thoroughly explaining the process in your response. I'm using it as a learning tool from here on in...thanks again!

Comment: Working code is [here](http://livetest.kaidez.com/) (site in progress as of this post).